# AssertionError: There should be two edges from model.start, two from Rainy, and two from Sunny

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, hidden-markov-models, pomegranate

While i was making model in HMM is stuck in problem AssertionError but couldnt figure out what the problem is?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from helpers import show_model
from pomegranate import State, HiddenMarkovModel, DiscreteDistribution



model = HiddenMarkovModel(name='Example Model')

#Emission probabiliy of distributions, p(umbrella|weather)
sunny_emission = DiscreteDistribution({'yes':0.1, 'no':0.8})
sunny_state = State(sunny_emission, name='Sunny')

rainy_emission = DiscreteDistribution({'yes':0.8, 'no':0.2})
rainy_state = State(rainy_emission, name='rainy')


model.add_states(sunny_state, rainy_state)

assert rainy_emission.probability('yes') == 0.8, "The director brings his umbrella with probability 0.8 on rainy days"
print("looks good so far")

model.add_transition(model.start, sunny_state, 0.5)
model.add_transition(model.start, rainy_state, 0.5)


model.add_transition(sunny_state, sunny_state, 0.8) # 80%sunny days
model.add_transition(rainy_state, rainy_state, 0.2) # 20% rainy days


model.add_transition(rainy_state, rainy_state, 0.6)
model.add_transition(rainy_state, sunny_state, 0.4)

model.bake()


assert model.edge_count() == 6, "There should be two edges from model.start, two from Rainy, and two from Sunny"
assert model.node_count() == 4, "The states should include model.start, model.end, Rainy, and Sunny"
```

> AssertionError: There should be two edges from model.start, two from Rainy, and two from Sunny

Answer (score 0):

the reason that you are getting that error is because , there are only 5 edges from the hidden state ('SUNNY') in your code but assert statement is checking for 6 edges .

```
**model.add_transition(rainy_state, rainy_state, 0.2) # 20% rainy days**
```

this is line where the error is , here the transition is from "rainy to rainy" instead of "sunny to rainy" .